# How to use Java or Groovy printf to add Thousands separator to String

Tags: java, groovy, printf

In Java, I need to add a thousands separator to a decimal number formatted as a **String**. However, I do **not** want a millions or billions separator... just a thousands separator with the existing fractional part of the number preserved.

9 == 9

999.999 == 999.999

9,999 == 9999

999999,999.999 == 999999999.999

I do not strictly need to use printf, but the conversion must be as fast as possible.

The input and output type must both be **String**.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at java.text.DecimalFormat?

Comment: Since the question required that the input and output must be of type String, wouldn't using DecimalFormat require you to parse the String to a number first and then format it back to a String?

Comment: I looked at DecimalFormat and did not think it would work for this. The question is quite specific and quite odd!

Comment: Yes it would need to convert to number and back again, and would certainly do the job.  I assumed that the op wanted something high level despite the need for efficiency, otherwise the obvious identify the index of the . and concatenate the lhs substring, a comma and rhs substring is probably the best solution, the concat could be done in an array but a stringbuilder would probably do.

Comment: I do not want to convert into a numeric type because I am worried about losing precision. I really think the type needs to remain a String. 

So far the only solution is to use String concatenation, parsing out the integral and fractional myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution so far is:

return text.replaceFirst("^(\d+)(\d{3})(\.|$)", "$1,$2$3");

Comment: this doesn't work, you need to escape your slashes as in my example

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, this issue is not as simple as it appears since the thousand separator is not always a comma and is dependant on the user's Locale.  In some cases it is actually a period, which may cause problems with any code you write for String manipulation.

If you wish to honour the user's Locale then a more considered approach is required, on the other hand, if you just want to take account of this one specific case and don't care about Locale settings then you could try something like this:

```
String s = "99999999.999";
s.replaceFirst("^(\\d+)(\\d{3})(\\.|$)", "$1,$2$3");
```

Comment: Note also that if you want to be culture-sensitive, it's not a "thousands separator" but a "grouping separator", because some east asian cultures have it every 4th digit rather than ever 3rd.

Comment: I do not want to honor anyone's locale. It must always be a comma and it must always be in the place normally referred to as the thousands place in US English. 

The above Regex will not solve the issue because the fractional part of the decimal is not guaranteed to be 3. The preference is to have the fractional part be arbitrarily long.

Comment: This regex does not work for the input 9999, which returns 9999 instead of 9,999. FWIW, here is a test case: 

[  ""        : "",         "9"        : "9",
"98"      : "98",       "987"      : "987",
"987.6"   : "987.6",    "987.65"   : "987.65",
"987.654" : "987.654",  "987.6543" : "987.6543",
"9,876"   : "9876",     "98,765"   : "98765",
"9876,543": "9876543",  "9,876.5"  : "9876.5",
"9,876.54": "9876.54",  "9,876.543": "9876.543",
"98764321978654,321.987654321" : "98764321978654321.987654321",
].each { expected, input ->
assert expected == input.replaceFirst("(\\d)(\\d{3}\\.)", '$1,$2')
}

Comment: I've updated the regex, this should properly handle all cases now.

Comment: no, the unit test still fails. This time "987.6543" is converted to "987.6,543".  -- insert pithy regex quote here --

Comment: here is the unit test in a web console: http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/61001

Comment: OK, so this time it _really_ works. Also checked against your Groovy console. Which is very groovy by the way.

Answer (score 0):

java.text.NumberFormat is what you need.

Visit https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html.

Comment: can people be so grateful as to explain why they give negative votes?

Comment: I gave negative votes because this is not possible with NumberFormat. It is the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def test='6816843541.5432'
index = test.indexOf('.')
test = test.substring(0,index - 3 ) + ',' + test.substring(index-3,test.size())
println test
```